# Can we implement Desktop Web Portal Application using IBM Worklight?

Tags: web-applications, ibm-mobilefirst

We are using IBM Worklight for Mobile apps development with Hybrid Application module. Same way we are planning to implement Desktop web based portal application using IBM Worklight (6.1.0) in Eclipse IDE.

Please help us in implementation with any configuration steps.

Answer (score 0):

There are no configuration steps to do. It it just another environment like all other environments.

This specific environment is basically a "web site". It is a URL that you will provide to your users to load in their desktop web browser.

Read the training modules:

- http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/02_09_Previewing_your_application_on_Mobile_Web_and_Desktop_Browser.pdf
- http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/03_13_General_information_when_developing_desktop_applications.pdf

Other than that,
This is a programming Q&A website. When you have an actual question - ask...